# How to create a full screen splash screen on iOS and Android using MAUI

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm new in MAUI , I want to display my app splash screen with image and texts and have a full screen image for the same. I replaced the default splash screen with this image, but in android the image coming as a round logo. On iOS also some UI issue are there. How to resolve this. Please help me.

I want the splash screen to look like below(Sample image) [image]

Comment: The official document said: **you shouldn't set the UILaunchStoryboardName key in your Info.plist file and you shouldn't add a LaunchScreen.storyboard to your app.**  So you can't custom a splash screen in the ios with maui. And for the android 12 and higher version, the image has a size limit in the native android. You can't do this in the android either.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT: I read that doc differently. For iOS, `MauiSplash.storyboard` is created. Presumably app dev can **modify** that storyboard as desired? The note you quote I think says not to change its name. [I have not tested.] The doc also says *"For more advanced splash screen scenarios, per-platform approaches apply."* For Android, it links to https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen. Summary: Maui does not have a *cross-platform* way to specify a splash screen, but each platform has a technique that can be used.

Comment: Having the same problem trying to figure this out. Did you find a way to accomplish this? Seems like such a basic feature that the Xamarin/Maui team continue to fail at.

Comment: Same issue looking for a solution

Comment: @Tsukasa  No, I'm still searching for a solution. If you get any solution,please share it here.

Comment: @Swathy Couldn't do it using maui, dont it with native approach only

Comment: @Suchith can you please share the native approach steps here.

Comment: @Swathy same as mentioned in doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen